# Refresh first fragment data

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have One Activity (**MainActivity**).
It have two fragment(**NewsTiltleFragment & NewsDetilsFragment**).
User lanch the app NewsTitleFragment is displayed.When user choose particular news title it shoud navigate NewsDetilsFragment.
when user return comeback to NewsTiltleFragment at that time i need to refresh the news.

Someone help me to solve this.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Please include your expected results, your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Please see the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to refresh.

There is way of broadcast receiver and the easier method is just call whatever you want to refresh in `onResume()` Method.

Comment: I replaced the first fragment(NewsTiltleFragment) that why on Resume not called

Comment: May be you are adding not replacing. because if you do replace you dont need resume too. It reload the previous fragment.

Comment: Finally i got it.

I used replace fragment and change AppcompactActivity to Activity.